# Why does this snapshot get every document twice? Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have something simple:

```
.snapshots()
  .listen((snapshot) {
      snapshot.documentChanges.forEach((doc) {       // Loop every document
        if (doc.type == DocumentChangeType.modified) { // If doc is modified
          print(doc.document.documentID);
        }
      });
  });
```

I have in total 2 documents and i listen to the collection where those documents are stored.
I want only the documentId of the changed one but i get this:

```
I/flutter ( 2785): bdfDfgsDg4TsdfadvGew
I/flutter ( 2785): bdfDfgsDg4TsdfadvGew
I/flutter ( 2785): bdfDfgsDg4TsdfadvGew
I/flutter ( 2785): bdfDfgsDg4TsdfadvGew
```

Why four times? If it was 2 times is get it because i have a foreach loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably what happens is your loop called every time the State is being built.
you are getting 4 because your state is rebuilt 2 time due to some reason.

can't say much without seeing the whole code. but above reason is the most common case.